# how invoking function as a callback parameter in function proceeded?

Tags: javascript, function

I am a beginner to JS world, and I have a question.
when I was studying .forEach() javascript function, I noticed that it takes 2 parameters, the first is a function and the second is the value of This obj and the normal usage like this:

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
}

// Notice that index 2 is skipped since there is no item at
// that position in the array.
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
```

but I noticed also that it can be called also like this:

example num 2 :

```
 [2, 5, , 9].forEach(function(){
console.log(arguments);
});
```

if .forEach() function takes a callback function as a parameter, how the second example is correct because it takes a function definition not a reference to a function which will be called,

I mean why it accepts a function definition in the second example although it takes a defined function name?

**I mean also that forEach need a reference to a function only, so when it loops on each element, it will just add () to the function reference so the function will be called**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, the parameter is an anonymous function as compared to first where you defined the function first and used it's reference to pass to .forEach(). So, both are essentially same. You can also write second example like

```
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(function(element, index, array){
    //do something with element
});
```

Comment: forEach in the first Example added the () to call the function, in the second, how it took the function definition, then set it to the argument then added () to call the function, the logic isn't fair.

Comment: @youhana functions in javascript are first class objects. The only difference between first and second is that in second, the callback is defined inside .forEach(). This is valid in Javascript.

Comment: your comment was the correct, I searched and revised this point and found that the function expression(anonymous function or not named function ) return a reference to the function that will equal the reference of the named or defined function, thank you ,

Answer (score 2):

function definition in javascript returns *pointer* to that function. You can also go through syntax like

```
let myFunction = function() { ... } // define function and save it into variable
myFunction() // call the defined function
```

So passing function by name and passing function definition is same thing

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [`Polyfill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example) what it does is it first check if the type of passed callback is a function and if it isn't then it throws an error, otherwise it uses `call()` to invoke that function so it doesn't matter if its anonymous function or function declaration.

It also checks if number of passed arguments is `>` 1 or if there is one more parameter after callback  and you can access that parameter with `this` in your callback.

```js
function invoke(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
  }

  if (arguments.length > 1) var Obj = arguments[1];

  var value = 1;
  callback.call(Obj, value);

}

invoke(function(e) {
  console.log(this)
  console.log(1 + e)
}, {foo: 'bar'})

var another = function(e) {
  console.log(10 + e)
}

invoke(another);
```

Comment: your answer was the best also but in case the forEach only , my question was about why the step before calling the callback step , because I was wondering how the function expression result is the same of the named function reference and the comments in the market correct result answered that, but your answer is very good for teaching me a new approach, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

to reach to the correct answer you have to: 
read the correct marked answer comments (the last comment), then read the answer **Nenad Vracar** as both of them covered my missed approaches, thanks for both of them.